# Access - How can i split the table records in two queries

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a table "Products" with n records(more than 5000 and always change the number). How can i generate two queries based on table, one for the first half of records and the second with the other half?

Comment: Do you have any column in the table that identifies the record-ID (running number from 1 to n, being n the number of records)?

Comment: How do you differentiate between the first half and second half keeping in mind that the order of records has no meaning in a database?

Comment: Hi! I have an IDNumber, but i need to use in queries another criteria. I think in Count records divide number of records on 2(generate an N integer) , in query select N top of records in the first query and create the second an unmatched query.
The structure of table is:
1.Id-Autonumber
2.ProductName-Text
3.Price-number

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What is special about each half? If it is a forms loading issue there are other ways around it.

Answer (score 1):

Using an AutoNumber primary key (or at least a field that has sequential numbering with no numbers missing) this may work - although I haven't really thought it through so may be a few pitfalls?

**Return the first half of ID numbers:**

```
SELECT  ID
FROM    Table1
WHERE   ID<=INT((SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Table1)/2)
```

**Return the second half of ID numbers:**

```
SELECT  ID
FROM    Table1
WHERE   ID>INT((SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Table1)/2)
```

Comment: It may work indeed but you rarely have autonumber IDs not missing. That's the only possible approach in pure SQL though, but not reliable

Comment: Agreed, definitely not reliable.

Comment: @Darren Bartup-Cook
Many thanks  Darren but I can´t use the id-Autonumber, that's because in the query i use another criterion the "Category".
Table structure is as follows:
ID -Auto
Category-Number
Product-Txt
Price-Curr.
When data is entered are inserted randomly
Id Product  Category          Price
1. 1.   Apple   $ 1.00
2. 2.   Rabbit   $ 4.00
3. 3.   Cheese   $ 8.00
4. 2.   Chicken  $ 3.10
5. 1.   Cherry   $ 2.50

If I choose Category "1" result:
Id Product  Category          Price
1. 1.   Apple   $ 1.00
5. 1.   Cherry   $ 2.00
I have two rec but the max Id is 5..

Comment: @Darren Bartup-Cook
As I said in the previous comment wich was not full, I apologize for that is my first post, I thinking to create query1 based on my Category criteria, next countrecords of this query, divide the countrecords number at 2 result a number N , create another query (Query2) based on Query1 and select N top of records and ultimately to create Query3 to show me the unmatched records between query2 and Query1. But I don´t have experience and I needed help to write QueryDef.

Comment: Yes, using MAX ID is not reliable - I'd go with @ThomasG solution, although you may need to add criteria to the DCOUNT function and SQL to pull out the required category.

Comment: One solution would be to make a custom VBA function that return the median value of a specific field and then use it as a criteria in your query, instead of using `INT((SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Table1)/2)`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you cant specify the result of a `COUNT(*)` subquery in the TOP instruction, so impossible to do this 100% reliably in pure SQL

The reliable alternative is to pre-build your 2 queries with VBA :

```
Sub Half_Table()

    Dim lngTotal As Long
    Dim lngHalf1 As Long
    Dim lngHalf2 As Long

    Dim strTable As String
    Dim strIDfield As String
    Dim strSQL1 As String
    Dim strSQL2 As String


    strTable = "table_Name"
    strIDfield = "ID"

    lngTotal = DCount("*", strTable)
    lngHalf1 = Round(lngTotal / 2)
    lngHalf2 = lngTotal - lngHalf1

    strSQL1 = "SELECT TOP " & lngHalf1 & " * FROM " & strTable & " ORDER BY " & strIDfield & " ASC"
    strSQL2 = "SELECT TOP " & lngHalf2 & " * FROM " & strTable & " ORDER BY " & strIDfield & " DESC"

    Debug.Print strSQL1
    Debug.Print strSQL2


End Sub
```

Change `strTable` and `strIDfield`  names accordingly.

This generates the 2 queries below with a table containing 1399 records :

```
SELECT TOP 700 * FROM table_Name ORDER BY ID ASC
SELECT TOP 699 * FROM table_Name ORDER BY ID DESC
```

I have not shown how to use the generated SQL queries
 afterwards as I assume you know that

Answer (score 0):

Consider the pure SQL solution using the row number count aggregate subquery:

**TOP HALF**

```
SELECT [ID], [Category], [Product], [Price]
FROM Products
INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT [ID], 
           (SELECT Count(*) FROM Products t2 
            WHERE Products.[ID] <= t2.[ID]) AS ProductOrder, 
           (SELECT Count(*) FROM Products t2) AS ProductCount
    FROM Products) AS sub 
ON Products.[ID] = sub.[ID]
WHERE sub.ProductOrder >= sub.ProductCount / 2
```

**BOTTOM HALF**

```
SELECT [ID], [Category], [Product], [Price]
FROM Products
INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT [ID], 
           (SELECT Count(*) FROM Products t2 
            WHERE Products.[ID] <= t2.[ID]) AS ProductOrder, 
           (SELECT Count(*) FROM Products t2) AS ProductCount
    FROM Products) AS sub 
ON Products.[ID] = sub.[ID]
WHERE sub.ProductOrder <= sub.ProductCount / 2
```